# Are common and differential mode chokes interchangeable?

Tags: inductor, differential, common-mode-choke

Is it possible to use a common mode choke as a differential mode by switching around one pair of wires and v.v. as shown on the drawing?
Intuitively it seems that this should work.
[image: CommonModeChokeAsDifferential]

I need a power differential choke so that I can send signals and provide power on the same bus.
It should be roughly 30mH and while there is a plethora of common mode chokes in this range, there are almost no differential ones ...

Thanks :)

Comment: a common mode choke will probably saturate if you try to use it differential

Comment: perhaps just use ordinary inductors? do you need differential mode?

Comment: Unfortunately differential is highly preferable.
Presuming the saturation would be a problem, would it be possible to use something else? For example a 1:1 transformer?

Comment: Please explain why differential would be preferable?

Comment: an ordinary  transformer will saturate same as the common-mode choke,you really want coupled inductors, ironically Digi-key calls these "pulse transformers" however in your application ordinary inductors should be almost as good.

Comment: What DC current must it carry? "differential is highly preferable" - why?

Comment: My bad, I meant that we have an existing one which works perfectly, and it looks like a 1:1 transformer, so I presumed it's a differential choke.
Let me start a new thread as identifying what it is seems like a new thing.

@BruceAbbott it needs to carry about 100mA @ 15V

Comment: The new thread for identifying what it is, is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351960/what-is-this-transformer-choke